# How is static charge in insulated shoe soles transferred to a person?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, everyday-life

Think of the typical static electricity scenario of touching a doorknob and there is a static discharge. We have an insulated floor, and insulated soles (a nylon carpet and rubber soled shoes). 
The static charge is transferred via triboelectricity to the soles. The charge is separated at the interface between the soles and the carpet, so how does the charge get transferred from the sole to the person?

If it does not, are we just observing the effects of induction from the sole's static charge? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the known spark discharge effect that can be noticed when touching a doorknob is not caused by the charges separated between the soles and the floor because these separated charges would not charge your body. Insulating soles or floors and usually a dry and thus insulating air are only required to prevent the discharge of your body capacitor to ground before it can lead to the spark phenomenon. The charging of you body capacitance (with respect to ground) probably happens by other triboelectric charging. I think, especially when you take off a coat, a sweater or other piece of garment (or when you give a rubbing hug to somebody else) you have charge separation and the separated charge remains on your body capacitance with respect to ground as long as you are insulated by insulating shoe soles or an insulating floor. When you then touch a grounded and conductive object you body capacitance can discharge again causing the spark.

Comment: I get more or fewer of these little "shocks" depending on which pair of shoes I'm using, so I think it does depend on the shoes.

Comment: It is certain that additional exchanges, such as the ones you've mentioned, would result in triboelectric charging, but if this were the only thing needed to have a discharge event, then this would happen on any surface (like a wood floor), but that is not the case.
I think the reality must be combination of induction and exchanges like the ones you mentioned. Could also be some type of leakage from the insulator into the body?

Comment: You are right. This probably depends on thedifferent  insulating qualities of your  shoes and different floors. Some conduct better than others.